# Why does having `<script>` in a string literal cause a JS syntax error?

Tags: javascript, escaping, string-literals, javascript-injection

Consider the following code:

```js
 var testVar = "<script>alert(\"a\")</script>@emaildomain.con";
```

In the console on FF, I get the error

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal.

However, if you change `script` to `xscript`, there is no error:

```js
 var testVar = "<xscript>alert(\"a\")</xscript>@emaildomain.con";
```

What is the proper way to escape `script` tags in JS, and why does including them in a string literal cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

The `</script>` part actually closes the starting tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var testVar = "<script>alert(\"a\")</script>@emaildomain.con";
</script>
```

So, your script is going to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var testVar = "<script>alert(\"a\")
</script>
@emaildomain.con";</script>
```

To solve the issue, you might do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var testVar = "<script>alert(\"a\")</" + "script>@emaildomain.con";
</script>
```